# Does robot framework provide a REST API for its execution of test scripts and processing result

Tags: robotframework

I am working on a open-source project. I want to be able to use Robot Framework as one of the functionality test Frameworks. So, is there any REST API that exists for the test script execution and it's results.

> MY TEST DRIVER <--- REST API  ---> ROBOT FRAMEWORK

Example: My test driver need to execute a script via the REST API. The Rest API would provide the path of the script to be executed. After executing the test cases, a result is expected in the response (JSON/XML/or any other).

Answer (score 0):

Aren't HttpLibrary and SSHLibrary enough for you?

http://peritus.github.io/robotframework-httplibrary/HttpLibrary.html
http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/latest/SSHLibrary.html

Comment: robot framework Http library are difficult to use, as they have do fill the rest object, parse the response, and validate it and if there are lot of test cases, there will be duplicate work across the test cases.

Comment: @MuraliMohanMurthyPotham Could you please elaborate more on what exactly you need? Robot Framework has some python APIs but not REST API.